# Can HttpResponseMessage.Content be null?

Tags: c#, http, .net-core, httpresponse, .net-core-3.1

Given the expression:

```
responseBodyJson = await responseMsg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Knowing that `responseMsg` is an `HttpResponseMessage` object and is not null, can `Content` (`HttpContent` object) be null, in other words, can this expression throw a `NullReferenceException` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that it will always create a new instance if it is null.

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpResponseMessage.cs

```
[AllowNull]
public HttpContent Content
{
    get { return _content ??= new EmptyContent(); }
    set
    {
        CheckDisposed();

        if (NetEventSource.Log.IsEnabled())
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                NetEventSource.ContentNull(this);
            }
            else
            {
                NetEventSource.Associate(this, value);
            }
        }
        _content = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This depends on what version of .net is running. This code is from the PR https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/35910 in the year 2020. Previous versions look to be able to return null.